# Error Generating Rig using Rigify Add-on after deleting a few bones

Tags: rigging, rigify

I intentionally deleted the bones for teeth and tongues, while using the rigify add-on. I am using the human meta rig. I was not aware of this previously. Those bones were completely unnecessary, so I thought I would simply remove them. While trying to generate the rig, it is giving errors like those particular bones not found type of error. I cannot recover the file because this mistake was done in the earlier stage. So, it's lost. Besides that, for the missing teeth part, I recreated bones, renamed them, and parented to the spine, so the error was gone. But for the tongue, I added another bone, named it tongue, then extruded it, like making tongue.001 to tongue.003. I parented this tongue to face bones, same error. Has anybody ever faced this? I even tried transferring the constraints from a duplicate meta rig, did copying pasting things, nothing is working. Need help sorting this out, will be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

None of the answers on the internet worked for me. So, I had to start from scratch observing a fresh meta rig and configure new bones to the problem. Here is the complete video solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8S8G2zeEQ8

Comment: Please avoid posting external links as an answer. If the link is invalidated at some point, this answer will also be incomplete. Thank you!

Comment: @quellenform is correct. Please read [this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) post, and then please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/279194/edit) your answer to include the steps to your solution. Link only answers may be deleted or converted into comments if not otherwise improved.